# Is an "International Driving Permit" from the AAA in United States valid in Bulgaria?

Tags: driving-license, bulgaria

Has anybody used an International Driving Permit (IDP) issued by the AAA in the US for car rental in Bulgaria?

Comment: An IDP is an official translation of your driver license.  You will be renting the car using your valid US driver license - the IDP is only used if requested by the rental car company.  I would be surprised if the rental company required your IDP (unless perhaps the country required you to hold one), but yes it should be accepted if required.  You will still need to carry your valid US license.

Answer (score 1):

> Is an “International Driving Permit” from the AAA in United States valid in Bulgaria?

Yes. Here is the list of countries in international driving permits issued on 2019-10-14 by AAA in United States. It includes Bulgaria:

[image]